# Problems creating a React-node app with npm

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

The instructions are as following:

> You are about to start creating a React-node app. Create the file
> package.json using npm commands.
>
> Make use of the following information:
>
> The name of the app should be npm_package. The start point will be
> index.js The project should have the following elements of
> dependencies
> - Install the latest version of react
> - Lodash with major version 4 and minor version 17,
> - Redux with Major version 4,
> - Mocha for testing in Dev,
> - Eslint with major version 6 in Dev.

Here is my virtual environment for reference:

[Virtual Environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sdk1.png)

I tried the following commands:

```
npm init -y

npm install react --save

npm install lodash@4.17.0 --save

npm install redux@4.0.0 --save

npm install mocha --save-dev

npm install eslint@6.0.0 --save-dev
```

Correctness is determined by the test file score.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
PASS=0
FAIL=0

TEST_1=$(grep -o -e "\"dependencies\"" -e "react" -e "\"redux\":\s*\"\^4.*\"" -e "\"lodash\":\s*\"\^4.17.*\"" /projects/challenge/package.json| wc -l)

TEST_2=$(grep -o -e "\"devDependencies\":\s*{" -e "\"eslint\":\s*\"^6.*\"" -e "\"mocha\":\s*" /projects/challenge/package.json| wc -l)

TEST_3=$(find /projects/challenge/node_modules | wc -l)

TEST_4=$(grep -o -e "\"name\":\s*\"npm_package\"" /projects/challenge/package.json| wc -l)

if [ "$TEST_1" -eq 4 ]
then ((PASS++))
fi;
if [ "$TEST_2" -eq 3 ]
then ((PASS++))
fi;
if [ "$TEST_3" -ge 1 ]
then ((PASS++))
fi;
if [ "$TEST_4" -eq 1 ]
then ((PASS++))
fi;

FAIL=$(( 4 - $PASS ))

echo "Test cases executed = 4";
echo "PASS = $PASS   FAIL=$FAIL"
```

Here is my console when I run the tests:

> user@workspace5zx0357qxb7p4nvt:/projects/challenge$ bash score.sh Test
> cases executed = 4 PASS = 3   FAIL=1
> user@workspace5zx0357qxb7p4nvt:/projects/challenge$

It does not tell me which test failed (or much of any other information) and therefore I dont know which of my commands I inputted is wrong or am I missing commands

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the first command.

1. Type `npm init` instead of `npm init -y`
2. It will ask you for package name – give `npm_package` as package name.
3. It will ask if you want to make starting point to `index.js`: press <kbd>enter</kbd>
4. Keep on pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> for the rest of the other configurations.
5. Once configuration is completed, start installing the packages one by one.
6. Add `index.js` file inside your project.

After this, try 'Run test' – all the 4 test cases will pass.

Answer (score -1):

Since no one has decided to reply, let me.
Just go into package.json and change the name to npm_package.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).